# Create Bitmap with transparent backgroud

Tags: android, bitmap, png, fromfile

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)
```

creates bitmap with black background, when I am selecting png format(transparent background) image from gallery, any suggestions ?

Comment: Is this Java and or Android? If so, please add the appropriate tags.

Comment: It's about Android